# Provide the 'allowthrottleablequeries' preference to allow this

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-api

I have developed an API using Microsoft Graph API. I am encountering below issue.

URL that I am calling :

```
/v1.0/sites/root/lists/cb32cc85-5351-423d-b2ec-bb418c1d9c64/items?
$filter=fields/Created gt '2018-1-1T00:00:00'
&expand=fields
&$orderby=createdDateTime
&$top=10
```

Error returned from the API :

> Field 'Created' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'allowthrottleablequeries' preference to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists.

How to enable `allowthrottleablequeries` as it says and how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't a very clear or useful error message. As far as I know, there isn't actually a way to enable `allowthrottleablequeries`.

This happens when a SharePoint list grows too large to handle filtering or sorting non-indexed columns. The fix is to add an index to the `created` column in your List Settings. You can find instructions on how to accomplish this in [Add an index to a SharePoint column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-index-to-a-SharePoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0).

Comment: I also get the same error on a standard SharePoint Online lists with **3 items** when I try to filter by the default **title** column like this: 

"graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/lists/<listId>/items?expand=fields&filter=startswith(fields/Title,'apple') "

This was working before and it stopped working few weeks ago. I also know that title columns are always indexed.
But this error occurs not matter which colums I choose. For me it looks like a bug.

Comment: Do you get this error every time? Regardless of the `List` you're working against?

Comment: Yes I tried multiple lists and different types of lists and also doc libs. All the same error. 

Today the error changed to: " Field 'Title' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'Prefer: **HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly**' header to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists."

Comment: Do you have a Correlation Id or Request Id from that call?

Comment: "request-id": "c36e9071-1235-4ca5-b2f8-0830832f371a",
"date": "2018-03-08T21:14:25"

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your request with following Request Header

**Prefer: allowthrottleablequeries**

If it does not work then try the following Request Header

**Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly**