# Microsoft Graph HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly Error when filtering SharePoint Online lists

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm using ms-graph with SharePoint Online.
I've a simple list with a single title column and 3 items.

I use the following ms-graph call to filter items by title:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/lists/list-guid/items?expand=fields&filter=startswith(fields/Title,%27fig%27)

The result is an error message:

> Field 'Title' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'Prefer: **HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly**' header to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists.

I know that this call was working before and also when I use SharePoint REST API then I can filter the list without any problems. I also tried different tenants.
Another fact is that the same call is working without the startswith filter.

Few days ago I had a different message for the same call.

> "Field 'Title' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the '**allowthrottleablequeries**' preference to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists."

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886356/provide-the-allowthrottleablequeries-preference-to-allow-this

Answer (score 11):

Regarding the following error:

> Field 'Title' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not
>   indexed. Provide the 'Prefer:
>   HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' header to allow this,
>   but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists.

at least two options are available to surpass this error while filtering.

### Option 1. Add an index to a SharePoint column

Once the [index to a SharePoint column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0) which participates in filtering is created, the error should no longer appear.

[image]

### Option 2. Append header `Prefer:HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly`

As the error message states append the specified header to request, for example in Graph Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just checked the Graph API Explorer and found out that you can use `allowthrottleablequeries` rather than `HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly`

Try to send your request with the following Request Header

```
Prefer: allowthrottleablequeries
```

Comment: Everyone else get an invalidRequest with "A field provided for filtering is not valid in that context"?