# How to fetch the SharePoint User Profile with Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Here's what I tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SiteID}/lists/{ListID}/items&filter=startswith(fields/Title,'Annette')
```

however I got the following error

```
"message": "Bad Request - Error in query syntax.",
```

How can I fetch the profile of the users from Sharepoint list that starts with "Annette"

Answer (score 0):

Append "?" symbol after items keyword.
Like :

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SiteID}/lists/{ListID}/**items?&filter**=startswith(fields/Title,'Annette')

It would work as expected ,as I reproduced same in my lab.

Comment: What did you use in startwith? I can not make it work by using `startswith(displayName,'a')`

Comment: @TonyJu I used a sample query here for test. and also append '**?**' before **&filter**. What error you are getting after following my comments?

Comment: generalException, An unspecified error has occurred.

Comment: @TonyJu Have you configured required permission [**Sites.Read.All, Sites/ReadWrite.All**] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items?$filter=(startswith(Title,'Annette')) `

here is still getting error

 `message": "Invalid filter clause `

Comment: @Mian1995 I tried this in my lab and concluded that you are getting this error because it **Could not find a property named 'Title' on type 'microsoft.graph.listItem'**. Search for item type that is available.

Comment: `cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' header to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists.`

Comment: @Mian1995 Check this solution for similar issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169917/microsoft-graph-honornonindexedquerieswarningmayfailrandomly-error-when-filterin