# Microsoft graph headers value "HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Hello,
if you want make a query on sharepoint ListItem using $filter clouse on non indexed field so I need to add on the header the key/value:
prefer   HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

I have not found documentation regarding this option and I do not know the consequences:
sometime the query fails with error?
sometime the query return wrong resultset?
resultset?  how I can know if the result are ok or with error?

Thanks
Lorenzo
Trento - Italy

Comment: Depending on the size of the data you're querying, non-indexed queries can be extremely slow. "May Fail Randomly" is a warning that queries may time out or otherwise fail due to load/resource contention. In other words, indexing is a _really_ good idea. :)

Comment: note that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169917/microsoft-graph-honornonindexedquerieswarningmayfailrandomly-error-when-filterin